# How to write the abscissa of the maximum under x'x

Tags: r, time-series

I'm plotting a time series data, say 'data1', I use `plot.ts(data1)`
then I use `abline(which.max(data1))`

Now I want to add the abscissa of the maximum point, say x-abscissa=19, but sometimes it appears confounded to the number that already exist in x-axis,
My question: how can I write the abscissa of the maximum below the number that already exist on x'x.

```
s=c(1,1.5,2,4,1,1,5,3,5,2,3,5,2,5,2,2,4,2,7,5,2,3,5,2,3,5,2,3,5,2,3,5) 
plot.ts(s)
abline(v=which.max(s), col= "red", lty=2, lwd=1)
axis(1,which.max(s))
```

Comment: Is `s` supposed to be the same as `data1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you Salman?

```
# axis(1,which.max(s))
library(glue)
label <- glue("Max is {max(s)}")
text(which.max(s), 0.2*max(s), label)
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. It works but it appears above x'x (inside the space of plotting the function). Is there a way to write between the x'x and the caption?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, OK, like this? Not really sure what x'x means.
(I swapped to tidyverse from base R, which is much easier to use, and gives beautiful plots)

```
library(glue)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

s <- c(1,1.5,2,4,1,1,5,3,5,2,3,5,2,5,2,2,4,2,7,5,2,3,5,2,3,5,2,3,5,2,3,5) 
s <- tibble(x = 1:32, y = s)
label <- glue("Max is {max(s$y)}")
ref_line <- which.max(s$y)
ggplot(s, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(tag = label) +
  theme(plot.tag.position = c(.65, 0.02)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = ref_line, col = "red")
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It works properly! and that is what I need.

Comment: Great news Salman!